# Wow Classic Macro/Addon to delete cheapest item

Tags: world-of-warcraft-classic

Is there a macro or addon for World of Warcraft to drop/delete/throw away the non-quest item in my bags with the lowest vendor sell price?

When my bags are full I hate trying to figure out what to drop when looting valuable things.

Comment: OneBag addon or similar can compactly display all loot at once and outline items by quality. Usually prices goes up with quality, so if you have gray items - dispose those first, doesn't really matter which one (keeping full stacks versus just few items, but also keep in mind which items you are about to get), then white items, etc. Not sure if there is sorting/filtering function, but you can also utilize that.

Comment: @Sinatr not quite.. there are actually a lot of greys that are supposed to be vendored and thus more expensive than others. Going by the color doesn't do the trick in classic's early game (where most of the loot is grey anyway).

Answer (score 2):

[DropTheCheapestThing](https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/dropthecheapestthing) does that: it gives you a little minimap button which you can click on to drop the cheapest thing. Also a merchant sell-junk button.